# relation betwen two random variables related by indicator function

Tags: probability, random-variables

If anyone can help me please
If we consider two continuous random variable $X$ and $Y$ ; we suppose that $Y_{i}=X_{i} \mathbb{I}_{A}$ where $\mathbb{I}_{A}$ the indicator of an event $A$, is that any relation between the Expected value of $X$ and $Y$ or other  mathematical expressions that related $X$ and $Y$?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$, $Y$ be r.v. and $Y = \mathbf{1}_AX$ for some event $A$ 
then $$\mathbb{E}(X | A ) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{Pr}(A)}\mathbb{E}(Y),$$
where $\mathbb{E}(X | A )$ is a [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) of $X$ given an event $A$.

Comment: are  there other  relations between X and Y (not necessarily for expected value)